# Prolog finding duplicates in a stucture gives existence error

Tags: prolog

I'm getting an existence error when I call my rule shareActors which should be true if two movies have the same actor. Thanks in advance!

```
movie(year(2003), title([pirates,of,the,carribean]), cast([actor(jonny, depp), actor(keira, knightley), actor(orlando, bloom)])).
movie(year(2014), title([guardians, of, the, galaxy]), cast([actor(chris, pratt), actor(karen,gillan) ])).                       
movie(year(1988), title([die,hard]), cast([actor(bruce, willis)])).                                                              
movie(year(2001), title([lord,of,the,rings]), cast([actor(orlando, bloom), actor(sean, bean)])).                                 
movie(year(2016), title([xmen, apocalypse]), cast([actor(jennifer,lawrence), actor(james, mcavoy)])).                            
movie(year(2014), title([the,imitation,game]), cast([actor(benedict, cumberbatch), actor(keira, knightley)])).                   
movie(year(2012), title([the,hunger,games]), cast([actor(jennifer,lawrence)])).                                                  
movie(year(2016), title([deadpool]), cast([actor(ryan, reynolds)])).                                                             

shareActors:-                                                             
        movie(_,_,cast(X)),
        movie(_,_,cast(Y)),
        intersect(X,Y,Z),
        Z \= [].
```

Comment: `intersect/3` is not defined but there is `intersection/3` in a [library](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=intersection%2F3).

Comment: Existence error regarding what? Please be specific. Show the message.

Comment: uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,intersection/3),shareActors/0)

Comment: That's the entire error message I change intersect to intersection but still got the same error.

Comment: You need to load the library.

Comment: Read the [documentation for `intersection/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=intersection/3). Make note of the "Availability" note near the top.